# HTML save screenshot of table as table background

Tags: html, html-table, background-image, screenshot

I'm using html2canvas to take a screenshot of table.

(code example found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-using-javascript/)

It's working fine, but instead of appending my document with the screenshot, I'd like to write it as new background-image into the table (It's actually a drawing thingy, where I try to save previous work as template or layer to add next...)

I'd be very happy for any hint.
This is the code:

html

```
<container>
  <div id="photo">
     <!-- Rendering GRID -->
     <table id="pixel_canvas"></table>
  </div>
</container>
<br>
<button onclick="takeshot()">
 Take Screenshot
</button><br>
<div id="output" </div>
```

and js

```
function takeshot() 
{
   let div = document.getElementById("photo");
   html2canvas(div).then(function (pixel_canvas) 
   {
   document.getElementById("output").appendChild(pixel_canvas);
   });
};
```

and I want to write "output" as bg-image into <pixel_canvas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html2canvas obviously returns a canvas, you have to convert it to image and set it the background-image

```js
function takeshot() 
{
   let div = document.getElementById("photo");
   html2canvas(div).then(function (pixel_canvas) {
      let pixel_canvas_element = 
      document.getElementById("pixel_canvas")
      pixel_canvas_element.style.background = `url(${pixel_canvas..toDataURL()})`;
   });
};
```

Comment: The problem was, that html2canvas seems to scale fact 2 by default.
I now set `html2canvas(div, { scale: 1,x: -50,y :-50 }).then(function (pixel_canvas) {` which solves the size prob.
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to accept % for x,y there in.
Now the image's x,y is at center of table

Comment: why not passing the height and width directly ?

Comment: as the grid gets dynamically rendered, I could calculate it, if nothing else helps

Comment: I mean get the height and width of the table inside the ```takeshot``` function and pass them to ```html2canvas```

Comment: got it running with rendering as `scale: 1` , then in table `position: center`